# How can I hide a select menu based on a radio button toggle in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

For some reason the select menu isn't hiding when I select "subscribe" radio option.

```js
            const $form = $('form');
            let subscription;

            let htm = '';

            htm += `
                    <div id="tcc-subscriptionType">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="subscription" value="once">
                            <span>One Time Purchase</span>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="subscription" value="subscribe">
                            <span>Subscribe and Save</span>
                        </label>
                        <select id="tcc-subscribe" name="term">
                            <option value="1">Once a month</option>
                            <option value="2">Every 2 months (save 10%)</option>
                            <option value="3">Every 3 months (save 15%)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                `;


            $form.append(htm);

            const $radio = $('#tcc-subscriptionType input[name="subscription"]')

            $radio.on('change', (e) => {
                subscription = $(e.target).val();
                console.log(subscription);
                if (subscription === 'subscribe') {
                    $('#tcc-subscribe').show();
                } else {
                    $('#tcc-subscribe').hide();
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
</form>
```

Comment: So when the user selects `One Time Purchase`, you want the dropdown select to hide correct?

Comment: Your code works find in the snippet that I have converted it to. Other than possibly adding a `style="display:none"` to the `tcc_subscribe` select it seems ok.

Comment: weird. when i add it to bigcommerce theme it doesn't hide.

Answer (score 0):

Change This only

```
 $radio.on('change', (e) => {
                subscription = $(e.target).val();
                console.log(subscription);
                if (subscription === 'subscribe') {
                    $('#tcc-subscribe').hide();
                } else {                        
                    $('#tcc-subscribe').show();
                }
            });
```